# NoMethodError in UsersController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm going through the railstutorial.org book and getting the error

when i signup the form i am getting error

NoMethodError in UsersController#create

my user_controller class is

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController


    def new
        @user = User.new
    end

    def show
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def create
        @user = User.new(params[:user])
        if @user.save
            redirect to @user
        else
        render 'new'
        end
    end

end
```

routes.rb file is

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :users


  root to: 'static_pages#home'


 match '/signup', to: 'users#new'

match '/help' , to:'static_pages#help'
match '/about' ,to:'static_pages#about'
match '/contact' , to: 'static_pages#contact'


  # The priority is based upon order of creation:
  # first created -> highest priority.

  # Sample of regular route:
  #   match 'products/:id' => 'catalog#view'
  # Keep in mind you can assign values other than :controller and :action

  # Sample of named route:
  #   match 'products/:id/purchase' => 'catalog#purchase', :as => :purchase
  # This route can be invoked with purchase_url(:id => product.id)

  # Sample resource route (maps HTTP verbs to controller actions automatically):
  #   resources :products

  # Sample resource route with options:
  #   resources :products do
  #     member do
  #       get 'short'
  #       post 'toggle'
  #     end
  #
  #     collection do
  #       get 'sold'
  #     end
  #   end

  # Sample resource route with sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments, :sales
  #     resource :seller
  #   end

  # Sample resource route with more complex sub-resources
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments
  #     resources :sales do
  #       get 'recent', :on => :collection
  #     end
  #   end

  # Sample resource route within a namespace:
  #   namespace :admin do
  #     # Directs /admin/products/* to Admin::ProductsController
  #     # (app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb)
  #     resources :products
  #   end

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  # just remember to delete public/index.html.
  # root :to => 'welcome#index'

  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes"

  # This is a legacy wild controller route that's not recommended for RESTful applications.
  # Note: This route will make all actions in every controller accessible via GET requests.
  # match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'
end
```

can anyone please help why i am getting this error.i am just a beginner on rails.so not able to rectify this error.

Comment: Don't know if it is a typo but the line `redirect to @user` is actually `redirect_to @user`.

Comment: I will post it as an answer so you can accept it ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was actually a typo in the redirect part of the create action on the controller. Changing `redirect to @user` to `redirect_to @user` solved it.